# Removing whitespace from {{ tag.name }}

Tags: tags

I'm using tags to do some Javascripting.

Is there any way that I can tell Craft to remove whitespace from {{ tag.name }} if the tag.name has spaces (for example 'apples and carrots'), and add dashes ('apples-and-carrots') ?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

There are multiple ways to solve this:

**Native:**

[Twigs `url_encode` filter](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/url_encode.html):

```twig
{{ "apples and carrots"|url_encode }}
{# outputs "apples%20and%20carrots" #}
```

[Twigs `replace` filter](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/replace.html):

```twig
{{ "apples and carrots"|replace(' ', '-') }}
{# outputs "apples-and-carrots" #}
```

**Plugins:**

[Twig PCRE Filters - Plugin](https://github.com/victor-in/Craft-TwigPCRE):

```twig
{{ "apples and carrots"|preg_replace('/ /', '-') }}
{# outputs "apples-and-carrots" #}
```

[Low Regex - Plugin](https://github.com/low/low_regex/):

```twig
{{ "apples and carrots"|regex('/ /', '-') }}
{# outputs "apples-and-carrots" #}
```

[Slugify - Plugin](https://gist.github.com/boboldehampsink/7354431):

```twig
{{ "apples and carrots"|slugify }}
{# outputs "apples-and-carrots" #}
```

Comment: If you want to handle "apples & *!@#@! carrots" then you need the slugify plugin

Answer (score 14):

Craft has a filter for "[Kebab Case](https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/filters#kebab)", which I think is what you need. It strips out punctuation and replaces spaces with dashes. Useful if you need to format a field as a HTML attribute.

```
{{ tag.name|kebab }}
```

Comment: Perfect answer. Worth noting that `kebab` didn't exist at the time this question was originally asked. It was added on **Jun 2, 2015**, when [Craft 2.4.2664](https://craftcms.com/changelog#build2664) was released.

Answer (score 9):

I'm not sure if this feature is newer than this question but you can also say `{{ tag.slug }}` to get `apples-and-carrots`. All letters become lowercase as well so the result is more "scripting-friendly".

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

one more example with array parameter in replace method:

```
{{ "apples and carrots"|replace({" ":"-"}) }}
{# outputs "apples-and-carrots" #}
```